# JOOQ Retrieving a Map from selectCount

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to get a map which is basically Map  and has booktype and count information from JOOQ. 
I have tried the following and different combinations but keep getting errors. any help would be appreciated:

```
    Map<String, Result<Record1<Integer>>> countMap = ctx.selectCount().from(BOOKTABLE)
         .groupBy(BOOKTABLE.TYPE)
         .fetchMAP(BOOKTABLE.TYPE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `selectCount()` in this case, because that will produce a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query, when you really want a `SELECT type, COUNT(*)` query.

Here are several ways how to do that, depending on what type you're trying to get out of the query:

```java
// Assuming this static import:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

Map<String, Integer> map1 =
ctx.select(BOOKTABLE.TYPE, count())
   .from(BOOKTABLE)
   .groupBy(BOOKTABLE.TYPE)
   .fetchMap(BOOKTABLE.TYPE, count());
```

Or:

```java
Map<String, Record2<String, Integer>> map2 =
ctx.select(BOOKTABLE.TYPE, count())
   .from(BOOKTABLE)
   .groupBy(BOOKTABLE.TYPE)
   .fetchMap(BOOKTABLE.TYPE);
```

Or:

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> map3 =
ctx.select(BOOKTABLE.TYPE, count())
   .from(BOOKTABLE)
   .groupBy(BOOKTABLE.TYPE)
   .fetchGroups(BOOKTABLE.TYPE, count());
```

Or:

```java
Map<String, Result<Record2<String, Integer>>> map4 =
ctx.select(BOOKTABLE.TYPE, count())
   .from(BOOKTABLE)
   .groupBy(BOOKTABLE.TYPE)
   .fetchGroups(BOOKTABLE.TYPE);
```

Comment: @Lukas Eder What if the column BOOKTABLE.TYPE has Null  and Empty values ? Will This query  group the empty and null values together as null ?

Comment: @vinaypatlolla: In Oracle: Yes, they're the same thing. In other databases: No, `NULL` and `''` are not the same thing.